# I want to play certain mp3 songs from a file on SD card simultaneously

Tags: android, android-emulator

First of all try to be patient I'm new in both android and asking questions
i wrote a code to play certain songs from a file on SD card ...but when i run the project on the AVD nothing happens. here is my code for playing those mp3 songs

```
private Button Play,Exit;
private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/Arabic/"); 
private MediaPlayer player;
private String a,z,startstr,endstr,namestr,soranamestr,firstayaname;
private int beginning,ending;
Thread thread;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Surat=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Surat);        
    Start=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Start);        
    End=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.End);        
    Play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    Play.setOnClickListener(playListener);
    Exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
    Exit.setOnClickListener(exitListener);

}

private View.OnClickListener exitListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {  
  try { 
        player.release();
        finish();        
        System.exit(0);
        }       
  catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                      }
                      };

private View.OnClickListener playListener = new View.OnClickListener() 
{   
  public void onClick(View v) {     
    play();
  }          
  };
  private void play()
  {

      try {

          player.reset();
          player.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH);
          player.prepare();
          player.start();

      } 
     catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }
```

Comment: actually I don't have an android device yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't play them on AVD. try to install the app on device and test it. AVD's don't have the native players installed in them. You can  also try the phonegap plugins to acieve this

Comment: why I played mp3 song on avd before

Comment: I think audio should work, I faced problems with video. Audio player is to be invoked

Comment: If you can use phonegap, try http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the player object somewhere, you only declare it, for example, in `onCreate`, add the line:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
```

Comment: I did that but also nothing is happening